# Ajax function in HTML not defined when all the parameters are correct

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Good day to everyone. So I have this Ajax request in which I will print a simple echo statement from another PHP file. Somehow, in the Ajax statement, it displays in the console:

> ReferenceError: senddocu is not defined

I was looking at the parameters in my Ajax code and I see no fault.

```
function senddocu(selected)
{
 $.ajax({   
    type: "POST",
    data: {staff: $(selected).val()},
    url: "localhost/htdocs/send.php",             
    dataType: "json",            
    success: function(response)
    {                    
        $("#responsecontainer").html(response); 
    }
    console.log(response);

}); 
}
```

Here is also the widget/ HTML Code:

```
<select name="staff" align="left" onchange="senddocu(this);">
    <option value="chief">Chief User</option>
    <option value="user">User 1</option>
</select>

<button type="button">Send</button></a>
```

I was also wondering how I could get the values of from the select option then with the button *Send*, it would trigger the function *senddoc* but I'm not entirely sure how to do bind that. I know about *onClick()* but not sure how to use it in this program.

Here is also the simple PHP print program I made in another file.

```
<?php
echo "<div id='responsecontainer'>";
if($_POST["staff"]=="chief")
{ echo "Document Sent!";
}
else if($_POST["staff"]=="sir")
{ echo "You got mail!";
} 
echo "</div>";
?>
```

I spent hours already looking for the problem to no avail. I would really appreciate any help if ever.Thanks so much!

Comment: Guess it's not global. Attach the handler properly using Javascript instead and you'll fix the problem, with the added bonus of avoiding global pollution

Comment: The syntax error in your function should be giving you an earlier error in your console ~ _"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"_

Comment: May I ask kindly if I you could tell me in a more specific way of where I went wrong? I'm still kind of learning the ropes. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in your ajax request, where your console.log is outside of the success callback.

Secondly, it looks like `#responsecontainer` isn't part of the page, rather it's in the response from `send.php`. You should probably move the div to your main page, so you can set the response there.

Here's the corrected AJAX call:

```
function senddocu(selected)
{
  $.ajax({   
    type: "POST",
    data: {staff: $(selected).val()},
    url: "localhost/htdocs/send.php",             
    dataType: "json",            
    success: function(response)
    {                    
        $("#responsecontainer").html(response); 
        console.log(response);
    }
  }); 
}
```

Comment: The code finally responds. Although the print statement isnt working.

Comment: What do you mean by the `print` statement? Is it part of `send.php`?

Comment: Yes yes. I would print them to a different webpage so I would know if it's connected to the senddoc function. As of now, I looked at the console log and it's sending 0B of data to send.php.

Comment: Hmm, you should be getting some data from `send.php`. Do you know if `send.php` works correctly?

Comment: Also, the url looks a little strange. Maybe try `url: "//localhost/htdocs/send.php"`?

Comment: I checked it by opening it up individually. Tried echoing something in the page. So it seems 'send.php' doesn't respond as I'd hope to be.

Comment: I changed it to only 'send.php' so it would only find the specific file instead of the directory since my 'send.php' is in the same directory as my ajax code.

Comment: Still not working. I dont know anymore. Maybe the problem is with 'send.php'?

Answer (score -1):

Please include jquery file below in your code

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js